# Integration Services 'All Execution Reports' Loads Forever

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to run my Integration Services (SSIS) package by deploying it to the SSIS catalog.

Then an error happened in my packages, so I went to check what it is by opening:

**Reports | All Executions | All Messages**

However, it never actually opens and loads forever:

[image: loads forever]

And when I tried clicking the refresh button, this error showed up instead:

[image]

I don't have any clue what's going on, and I don't remember it ever being like this before, so something (or someone) must have been changing things.

Where should I check on this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my SSIS package was so ineffective that it heavily consumes memory, causing the sessionID of SSISDB SUSPENDED (figured it out by using `sp_who2`)

I kill all the problematic suspended sessions, and the SSIS Execution Report works again!